# ComboBox.SelectedItem Issue C#

Tags: c#, combobox, selecteditem, selectedindex

I have an application in which I am allowing a user to load the selections they previously made in a form and then allowing them to save changes.  The problem is that when I load items into a combobox and change the selectedIndex or selectedItem programmatically it is not working.  For exacmple if I assign the selectedIndex to the first item that comboBox will not pass through an if statement I have that checks if the selectedIndex is -1.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to programmatically assign a selectedIndex or selectedeItem to a comboBox in which the items were also programmatically added so that it will work in this situation.  Thanks

```
XmlNode trialNumber = doc.SelectSingleNode(pathString + "/trial");
selectTrialNumberComboBox.SelectedItem = trialNumber.InnerText.ToString();
selectTrialNumber = trialNumber.InnerText.ToString();
selectTrialNumberComboBox.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: I'd recommend posting the code you used to set the selected index

Comment: Code would be king here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
selectTrialNumberComboBox.SelectedIndex = selectTrialNumberComboBox.Items.IndexOf(selectTrialNumberComboBox.Items.FindByText(trialNumber.InnerText.ToString()))
```